# VSCode Intellisense C++ does not detect forward slash in include files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have a problem with VSCode Intellisense C++, it fails to detect the include files specified in this format:

```
#include <foo/bar.h>
```

Although the directory foo is included in both includePath and browse:path.

I'm not using VSCode for compilation, but I want to make use of its linting capabilities. However all the squiggles are disabled as some includes cannot be resolved.

Comment: It works just fine for me without any `.vscode` files. Are you using CMake and CMake tools extension?

Comment: No I don't use it as I have a separate build environment. I only use VSCode to navigate the project. Would it help?

Comment: Not unless you already build via CMake, doesn't matter in VSCode or not, it just requires CMake's cache. At least for my setup. I'm not sure maybe there are extensions for other build systems like plain Ninja / Meson, if you use one